# How to get the size of gzip compressed response in .NET Core 6.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, gzip, asp.net-core-6.0

I have an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API solution. I have added a gzip compression middleware to compress the API response, now I want to check the size of compressed response.

How I can check the gzip compressed size?

I tried to get the length of compressed response body but it throwing error.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show the code you tried? What error message do you get?

Answer (score 0):

You can use in the same middleware by getting the Compressed Size by using stream and add it to the response header as content-length

If you can show the code you tried it will be much more helpful

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).